# Kendo UI Grid: Get the data of Current Grouping state?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Please See the [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AxeFi)

When user drag columns to the top for grouping, I want the data of how they group the data. For example if they first group the data by "ProductName", then "UnitsOnOrder". I want to pro grammatically get the data {"ProductName", "UnitsOnOrder"} to show that they group the data with these variables and in this sequence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[dataSource.group()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-group)** to get the columns currently being grouped by:

```
  $('#click').click(function() {
    var groups = [];
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var gridgroups = grid.dataSource.group();
    for (var i=0; i< gridgroups.length; i++){
      groups.push(gridgroups[i].field);             
    }

    alert(groups);       
  })
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UKOLa)**